# OpenHAB Missing Binding

Tags: binding, openhab

I installed mosquitto on my Raspberry Pi.
I installed the MQTT Binding, MQTT Binding (1.x) using PaperUI.
I created an item:
Number mqtt_kitchen_gas "Gas Level [%.1f]" {mqtt="<[mosquitto:Home/Floor1/Kitchen/Gas_Sensor:state:default]"}
I opened a terminal window and sent:
mosquitto_pub -u openhabian --pw xxxx -t "Home/Floor1/Kitchen/Gas_Sensor" -m 10

The value "10" appeared in the Gas Level field.
I could change "10" to any number and that would appear in the field.
All was good with the world.

Then I rebooted and looked for the binding MQTT.  It is not listed under Configuration, Bindings. (GPIO, another binding I installed is listed.)  Also, if I search the Add-ons for MQTT it shows MQTT Binding (1.x) is installed (can be uninstalled) and I can still change the Gas Level field using the above mosquitto_pub.

Maybe I shouldn't worry about it since it works but maybe I have something wrong with my installation and it will come back to bite me.
Any opinions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure (about 75% :D), but i think that the MQTT 1.x Binding simply doesn't provide any configuration that could be done in paper ui.
That could be the reason why it isn't displayed in the config section.

Since it appears in the addons section and works, everything should be fine.
I am using this binding too and it works  properly for ages.
Of course i checked my configuration area in paper ui and it isn't shown there for me too.

Anyways its always fine to check the logs regularly for problems.
If there are none, installation is fine.

Comment: @J I think you are right.  I have been running mqtt for over two months and it is "pretty reliable".  However it does seem to die after two or three days.  That is about 300 "publishes".  I believe the program that publishes is still publishing but none of the subscribers are getting anything.  I have been trying to work with the log but it is so filled with things I don't understand I can't get anywhere.  But now that I have other things working better I will have to learn to interpret the log.

Comment: You can find some information on logging here:
https://www.openhab.org/docs/administration/logging.html

I have turned off many log types which cleans up the log heavily.
You could also go for a special log file, for mqtt related logs to get a focused timeline of whats happening especially for this binding.